# Unix: replace variable in file a with value in file b

Tags: linux, shell

I have two files in Linux, in file a there are variables like these:

```
${VERSION} ${SOFTWARE_PRODUCER}
```

And the values of these variables are stored in file b:

```
VERSION=1.0.1
SOFTWARE_PRODUCER=Luc
```

Now how can I use command to replace the variables in file a with values in file b? Is something like `sed` able to do this task?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `bash` loop would suffice:

```
$ cat a
This is file 'a' which has this variable ${VERSION} 
and it has this also:
${SOFTWARE_PRODUCER}
$ cat b
VERSION=1.0.1
SOFTWARE_PRODUCER=Luc
$ cat script.bash 
#!/bin/bash
while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    key=$(awk -F= '{print $1}' <<< "$line")
    value=$(awk -F= '{print $2}' <<< "$line")
    sed -i 's/${'"$key"'}/'"$value"'/g' a
done < b
$ ./script.bash 
$ cat a
This is file 'a' which has this variable 1.0.1 
and it has this also:
Luc
$
```